# How to get a div with multiple classes count using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sample HTML like the following,

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2 class3"></div>
```

And my JS is,

```
alert(jQuery(".class1").length);
alert(jQuery(".class2 class3").length);
```

For the first alert I am getting 1 as expected, but I am getting 0 for the second alert. How to get the value 1 for the second alert as well. I need specifically this case (where a div has both class2 and class3). Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want `'.class2.class3'`

What you have (`'.class2 class3'`) means "A `<class3>` element that is a descendent of an element that is a member of *class2*".

Answer (score 3):

Take out the space and you're missing a dot, the selector you're looking for is `$('.class2.class3')`

Answer (score 1):

`('.class2 class3')` has no meaning.

`('.class2 .class3')` : an element with `class3` which is **a child of** an element with `class2` .
`('.class2.class3')`: an element which has `class2` **AND** `class3`, **both**.